# Why Other Process Still Runs When the application encouters OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

We come across the error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit" in the log files and other process also running after this error

1. Why other process is also running after the above error?
2. Does all the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError errors will block the entire application or not?

Assume there are 10 threads out of which one thread got failed with OutofMemory error. In such a case will all the threads will be blocked or other 9 threads will continue the process

Example logger message:

```
example...(QuartzScheduler.java:2166) - Job (DEFAULT.jobLaunchStatusPoller threw an 
exception. org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested      
exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit] at 
org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210) at 
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546) Caused by: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit [Mar 17 13:32:24] 
[3578814] WARN [PollingScheduler_Worker-19] (JobExecutor.java:54) - Job Execution 
Started.
```

Thanks.

Comment: An "OutOfMemoryError" is just an exception, though one that can rarely be handled successfully.  If/when it ripples down to the base of the thread stack, the thread default handler is invoked.  That handler may or may not decide to take down the rest of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: [Effects of uncaught exceptions on threads from Quartz's SimpleThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574777/effects-of-uncaught-exceptions-on-threads-from-quartzs-simplethreadpool)

Quartz sets an uncaught exception handler for its threads, which catches `Throwable` and in turn refills its threadpool with a new thread.

Normally (without quarz or any other set UncaughtExceptionHandler), the Error would be propagated up to the default handler, which would exit the VM and print the stacktrace. So in your case:

1. see above, only the failed thread is dropped
2. With quartz, all `OutOfMemoryError`s would be treated the same way (as would all other errors), however, most other Errors would usually leave your VM in an inconsistent state. "Requested array size exceeds VM limit" is one of the rarer errors, which are totally recoverable, because they do only affect one thread.